# ESP32 deep Sleep wakeup with disabled RF

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp32

I used to use esp8266 with its deep sleep options to wake up with timer and to wakeup with disabled RF like this
 `ESP.deepSleep(TimeInMicro, WAKE_NO_RFCAL);`
However now I am using esp32. I found how to wake it up with timer but I could not find an option to wakeup with disabled RF.
my question is this option possible in esp32 and how to implement that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: http://esp-idf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-reference/system/sleep_modes.html

> #### WiFi/BT and sleep modes
>
> In deep sleep mode, wireless peripherals are powered down. Before
>   entering sleep mode, applications must
>   disable WiFi and BT using appropriate calls ( `esp_bluedroid_disable`,
>   `esp_bt_controller_disable`, `esp_wifi_stop`).
>
> WiFi can coexist with light sleep mode, allowing the chip to go into
>   light sleep mode when there is no network activity, and waking up the
>   chip from light sleep mode when required. However APIs described in
>   this section can not be used for that purpose. `esp_light_sleep_start`
>   forces the chip to enter light sleep mode, regardless of whether WiFi
>   is active or not. Automatic entry into light sleep mode, coordinated
>   with WiFi driver, will be supported using a separate set of APIs.

There's a list of all the parameters you can configure with `esp_deep_sleep_pd_config` prior to entering deep sleep, along with rich information about lots of other deep sleep topics.

For example you can do this sort of thing, exercising a fine degree of control over how your device deep sleeps:

```
esp_deep_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_RTC_PERIPH, ESP_PD_OPTION_OFF);
esp_deep_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_RTC_SLOW_MEM, ESP_PD_OPTION_OFF);
esp_deep_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_RTC_FAST_MEM, ESP_PD_OPTION_OFF);
esp_deep_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(((uint64_t) sec) * 60);
esp_deep_sleep_start();
```

Comment: Didn't mean to write `esp_sleep_pd_config` instead of `esp_deep_sleep_pd_config` as per https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/system/sleep_modes.html#_CPPv419esp_sleep_pd_config21esp_sleep_pd_domain_t21esp_sleep_pd_option_t

Comment: Regarding the actual question "I could not find an option to wakeup with disabled RF"... the way I read the spec is that if you use `esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup` the firmware will turn off all peripherals **including modem**. Hence, that is equivalent to `WAKE_NO_RFCAL ` on the ESP8266.